# Converting Number to Words

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function which converts words to numbers but when the number is for example '4500' the output that is gives you is 'Four Thousand Five Hundred AND'

I want the AND to be removed at the End of the words result

below is the function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spell_number (p_number IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   TYPE myArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);

   l_str      myArray
                 := myArray ('',
                             ' thousand ',
                             ' million ',
                             ' billion ',
                             ' trillion ',
                             ' quadrillion ',
                             ' quintillion ',
                             ' sextillion ',
                             ' septillion ',
                             ' octillion ',
                             ' nonillion ',
                             ' decillion ',
                             ' undecillion ',
                             ' duodecillion ');

   l_num      VARCHAR2 (50) DEFAULT TRUNC (p_number);
   l_return   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_str.COUNT
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN l_num IS NULL;

      IF (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3) <> 0)
      THEN
         l_return :=
               REPLACE (
                     TO_CHAR (
                        TO_DATE (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'),
                        'Jsp')
                  || l_str (i),
                  'Hundred',
                  'Hundred AND')
            || l_return;
      END IF;

      l_num := SUBSTR (l_num, 1, LENGTH (l_num) - 3);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_return;
END;
```

Comment: You explicitly replace 'Hundred' with 'Hundred AND' in your code. Why, if you don't want the 'AND'?

Comment: if remove it manually when i have a number like '44556345000' the output will be Forty-Four billion Five Hundred Fifty-Six million Three Hundred Forty-Five thousand  which doesnt make any sense

Comment: @Phraseassembler It makes perfect sense, actually...  Just don't use `AND` in the result at all.  `115` is `One hundred fifteen` not `One hundred and fifteen`.

Comment: I agree with @Siyual; However, if you only want to remove the final AND, simply edit your code: `RETURN rtrim(l_return, 'AND');`

Comment: it doesnt correct it

Comment: this removes the final AND, as asked. If you need something different, please edit your question to show a wider example and clarify your need

Comment: Are you running Oracle EBS?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the final `'AND'`, you can simply edit your code this way:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spell_number (p_number IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  AS
  4     TYPE myArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);
  5
  6     l_str      myArray
  7                   := myArray ('',
  8                               ' thousand ',
  9                               ' million ',
 10                               ' billion ',
 11                               ' trillion ',
 12                               ' quadrillion ',
 13                               ' quintillion ',
 14                               ' sextillion ',
 15                               ' septillion ',
 16                               ' octillion ',
 17                               ' nonillion ',
 18                               ' decillion ',
 19                               ' undecillion ',
 20                               ' duodecillion ');
 21
 22     l_num      VARCHAR2 (50) DEFAULT TRUNC (p_number);
 23     l_return   VARCHAR2 (4000);
 24  BEGIN
 25     FOR i IN 1 .. l_str.COUNT
 26     LOOP
 27        EXIT WHEN l_num IS NULL;
 28
 29        IF (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3) <> 0)
 30        THEN
 31           l_return :=
 32                 REPLACE (
 33                       TO_CHAR (
 34                          TO_DATE (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'),
 35                          'Jsp')
 36                    || l_str (i),
 37                    'Hundred',
 38                    'Hundred AND')
 39              || l_return;
 40        END IF;
 41
 42        l_num := SUBSTR (l_num, 1, LENGTH (l_num) - 3);
 43     END LOOP;
 44
 45     RETURN rtrim(l_return, 'AND');
 46  END;
 47  /

Function created.

SQL> select spell_number('4500') from dual;

SPELL_NUMBER('4500')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Four thousand Five Hundred

SQL>
```

Comment: not working the AND still appears at the end for amount of 4500

Comment: yes it works with four digit numbers but when the number increases the And vanishes

Comment: This answers the question. If you have a different need, edit your question posting some more examples and desired results

Comment: so there is a new hurdle when there is a number like 500,000 is makes it Five Hundred AND thousand  @aleksej

Comment: I believe you need no AND at all; number spell does not contain AND. If you want it, try to specify when and where you want to add an AND.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to see AND between hundreeds and tens or number 
I mean '556003000'  should be 'Five Hundred AND Fifty-Six million Three Thousand' 
and '500003000' should be 'Five Hundred million Three Thousand' without AND

You may add check

```
cur_num := SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3);
IF MOD(cur_num, 100) != 0 THEN
  ... REPLACE ( TO_CHAR (
                       TO_DATE (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'),
                       'Jsp')
                 || l_str (i),
                 'Hundred',
                 'Hundred AND');
  ... 
ELSE 
  ...
  TO_CHAR (
                       TO_DATE (SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'),
                       'Jsp')
                 || l_str (i);
  ... 
END IF;
```

Changed function look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spell_number (p_number IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   TYPE myArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (255);

   l_str      myArray
                 := myArray ('',
                             ' thousand ',
                             ' million ',
                             ' billion ',
                             ' trillion ',
                             ' quadrillion ',
                             ' quintillion ',
                             ' sextillion ',
                             ' septillion ',
                             ' octillion ',
                             ' nonillion ',
                             ' decillion ',
                             ' undecillion ',
                             ' duodecillion ');

   l_num      VARCHAR2 (50) DEFAULT TRUNC (p_number);
   l_return   VARCHAR2 (4000);
   l_cur_num  VARCHAR2(3); 
   l_cur_text  VARCHAR2(4000); 
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. l_str.COUNT
   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN l_num IS NULL;
      l_cur_num := SUBSTR (l_num, LENGTH (l_num) - 2, 3);

      IF (l_cur_num <> 0)
      THEN
    l_cur_text := TO_CHAR ( TO_DATE (l_cur_num, 'J'), 'Jsp')|| l_str (i); 
        IF MOD(l_cur_num,100) != 0 THEN 
          l_cur_text := REPLACE (l_cur_text, 'Hundred', 'Hundred AND');
        END IF;  
        l_return := l_cur_text || l_return;
      END IF;

      l_num := SUBSTR (l_num, 1, LENGTH (l_num) - 3);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_return;
END;
```